# PHP: Error when user uploads image to site

Tags: php, forms, image, file-upload, directory

I am trying to let a user upload an image and that image will stay in a folder called, "Images." I am not sure if I am formatting this correctly because the tutorial I am following isn't using a server.

Here are the errors that I currently get:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/TrollFace.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/benrud/public_html/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/account.php on line 13

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpVzhJCX' to '/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/TrollFace.jpg' in /home/benrud/public_html/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/account.php on line 13

[Here is the link to the folder](http://foothillertech.com/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/)

Below is my code.Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post the errors you are seeing into your question. It is more helpful than a link to a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: Does the destination folder exist on your server?
And the user that runs the webserver has `write` right to this folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
//images may be many, just load into a named array 
$filesArray = $_FILES;

//first properly target your directory (which should have write permission)
$ximage = "ppsize_photo";   //actual name or id as in html 
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/"; 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($filesArray[$ximage]["name"]);
$ext1 = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imageFileType = $ext1;     //you may use this later to reject some types 

//ensure that your file names are unique (use any means possible)
$unique_id = substr( base_convert( time(), 10, 36 ) . md5( microtime() ), 0, 16 );
$unique_id1 = $unique_id . "." . $ext1; 
$target_file = $target_dir . $unique_id1;   //complete file name; maybe here is where your error was 

//you may also validate the extensions; it may not be an image 
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    exit();
}else {
    //fine
}

//now move the image 
$uploadFlag = false;
if (move_uploaded_file($filesArray[$ximage]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //it went fine 
    $uploadFlag = true;             
} else {
    //echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    $uploadFlag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your destination path... I believe Your destination path is invalid